# directives of Angularjs 1 with Cytoscape.js

Tags: angularjs, cytoscape.js

I am working on the library cytoscape.js with Angularjs 1 and I would like to know how to apply the directives of Angularjs such as ng-show to display for example a part of the nodes of the graph. thank you in advance

Comment: Please use english.

Comment: Execuse me, Hello, I am working on the library cytoscape.js with Angularjs 1 and I would like to know how to apply the directives of Angularjs such as ng-show to display for example a part of the nodes of the graph. thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use angular, you have to either forgo it in the code where you use Cytoscape or you have to write your own directive that uses Cytoscape within it.